# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException. Not able to connect to application on HTTPS?

Tags: java, https, jsessionid

hi i am using tomcat 6 as webserver.  i have two webbapplication installed on tomcat on same port. Say App1 and App2.  App1 connects to
App2 . Then App2 again connects to App1 using jessionid(so url which app2 is sending is http://localhost/App1;jessionid=sessionidOfAp11)
It works perfectly fine as long as i am on http. But as soon as i move to https App2 is not able to connects to App1 with same url.
Another interesting fact is if i type same url on Brower , it connects to App1. **I am  not getting what is the mystery going here?**

Edit :- here is the exact error i get

```
 Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid  certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 53 more
 Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
```

**Answer**

Guys thanks for answer. Alon with ramesh answer i also had to do the stuff suggested at  http://www.coderanch.com/t/134384/Security/Getting-error-No-subject-alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by "App1 connects to App2"?

Comment: Do you use https for both applications? Or just for App2?

Comment: Basically on click of link on App1 call goes to App2. then App2 again connects to App1 to check some logic with api URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

Comment: @ a.tereschenkov. When i open individual sites with https it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because App1 is connecting to App2 using https. **The certificate of App2 should be there in the trust store of VM where the App1 runs**.

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) to see how to add certificate to the keystore.

You can set the truststore using these system properties

```
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/test/truststore"  
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="test".
```

Moreover you dont have to communicate over https when client and server are there on

- Same VM
- Same Machine
- Private Network

Comment: Ramesh how should i add certificate of App2 should be there in the trust store of VM where the App1  lies

Comment: If same VM, just point the truststore to your server certs file.

Comment: <Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

Comment: Look for ssl connector in server.xml, It might be having the server keystore. Use the same store and password as truststore.

Comment: here is the entry in server.xml of App1 <Connector 
      SSLEnabled="true" 
      acceptCount="100" 
      connectionTimeout="20000" 
      executor="tomcatThreadPool" 

      keystoreFile="c:/.keystore" 
      keystorePass="changeit" 
      maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
      port="8443" 
      protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
      redirectPort="8443" 
      scheme="https" 
      secure="true" 
      allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation="true"/>. But not getting where is trust store  and how to use  same store and password as truststore?Both are in same tomcat and same vm

Comment: sorry for asking this, I have to do this in another 30 minutes for demo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8538/discussion-between-m-sach-and-ramesh-pvk)

Comment: Thanks Ramesh a lot . What you told was correct. But alongwith that i also had to do the stuff suggested at http://www.coderanch.com/t/134384/Security/Getting-error-No-subject-alternative.

Comment: Welcome. Yes, i know that you have to add HostNameVerfied. But for that you have to get exception of different type. Anyways , it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to remove native tomcat library from {tomcat_home}/bin folder (tcnative-1.dll under windows, maybe tcnative-1.so under *nix). Tomcat uses APR if native library is in classpath. Read more about configuring SSL [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: There is no library like this under bin folder